# Writing to a GPIO pin on the Orange Pi Zero with Mono

Tags: mono, gpio, orange-pi, armbian

I wrote a Mono app for Armbian Ubuntu running on an Orange Pi Zero to read incoming telemetry data from the serial port.
That part is working fine, but I now need to activate one of the pins on the GPIO. I simply have to occasionally set pin 19 to high for about a second and then clear it again.
Unfortunately, I'm struggling quite a bit with this. Whereas reading the serial port was relatively easy, I'm quite lost on writing to a GPIO pin with Mono.
If any one has any pointers I'd greatly appreciate it. Perhaps a sample or an idea of which library I should be using would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: If your OS supports the `/sys/class/gpio` interface you can use plain simple file system operations.

Comment: Thanks Jester - funny enough I came across some sample code last night that does just that